# How to automate windows security pop up - Robot Framework

Tags: robotframework

I'm quite new in test automaton. I'm using Robot Framework with Selenium Library and struggling to handle the Windows security window. It pops up when I wanna login to my application.
[windows security pop up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D3QCI.png)

I know that Selenium can not handle this, but have no idea how to solve that. Did anyone managed this type of issue?